# fontloader and textgeometry not working in threejs

Tags: javascript, import, module, three.js

I need to render some text in my threejs project, but every time I add the module

```
import { FontLoader } from 'https://threejs.org/examples/jsm/loaders/FontLoader.js';
import { TextGeometry } from 'https://threejs.org/examples/jsm/geometries/TextGeometry.js';
```

this error is thrown

```
Uncaught TypeError: Error resolving module specifier “three”. Relative module specifiers must start with “./”, “../” or “/”. FontLoader.js:5:7
```

Which is coming from FontLoader.js. If I don't include any of it three js render the scene and works fine. In my network log, it runs flawless and all modules are 200 OK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use an import map with latest `three.js` releases. Besides, never import modules directly from `https://threejs.org`. Always use a CDN like below:

```
<script async src="https://unpkg.com/es-module-shims@1.3.6/dist/es-module-shims.js"></script>

<script type="importmap">
    {
        "imports": {
            "three": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.138.3/build/three.module.js"
        }
    }
</script>

<script type="module">

    import * as THREE from 'three';

    import { FontLoader } from 'https://unpkg.com/three@0.138.3/examples/jsm/loaders/FontLoader.js';
    import { TextGeometry } from 'https://unpkg.com/three@0.138.3/examples/jsm/geometries/TextGeometry.js';
```

The polyfill `es-module-shims.js` is currently required in Firefox and Safari.

Answer (score 3):

The error you are receiving is because you are importing JS example files whose are in fact ESM modules, but inside them they have imports from `three` that cannot be resolved.

ThreeJS exports `FontLoader` and `TextGeometry` so you just need to import a EcmaScript Module (ESM) from a CDN to import, for example:

```js
import { FontLoader, TextGeometry } from 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r128/three.module.js';
```

By that way they will be available in Chrome.

Comment: not working for me